# CakePHP action only happen once a boolean is met

Tags: mysql, validation, cakephp

Hey we are trying to validate an account in CakePHP but only if a boolean is met.

A user can only receive or send an invoice if they have a relationship with another user.

But we are unsure how to do this in CakePHP.

This is our pseudo code that we believe will do it in normal PHP with MYSQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_insert
Before Insert ON Invoices FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
if i.receiverid, i.senderid
where = r.partyone, r.partytwo
active = 1

SEND INVOICE

else

SEND ERROR "no relationship exists"
```

Comment: You can use the beforeSave or beforeValidate callback to do your check there. If you return false in those methods, saving will stop. Or do you strictly want it sql only?

Comment: Thanks. No we don't want it strictly SQL only. So this will still work if it's not strictly SQL?

Comment: Yea, that will work. If the id input of either party is visible in the form, you can add a custom validation rule to that field. See the book for custom validation rules. If you need help, post back with what you have tried.